# Measurable and lebesgue measurable sets

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, geometric-measure-theory, measurable-sets

Which set I say that it's measurable set, and which one is a Lebesgue measurable set !!! 
I read that the Set which is applied on Lebesgue measure is a sequence of small intervals. so what about the general measure.
To be clear, what's the diff between the outer measure and Lebesgue outer measure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given a $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{F}$ on a set $\Omega,$ we say that the sets $A\in\mathcal{F}$ are $\mathcal{F}$-measurable.

[In this Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outer_measure), you can see how an outer measure is defined, and how an outer measure gives rise to a $\sigma$-algebra of measurable sets, for which the measure equals the outer measure (by definition).

Both concepts can then be specialized to the case of Lebesgue outer measure/ Lebesgue measurable sets by taking the appropriate notion of outer measure.